# Non-terminating recursive use of decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion

Compilation of the following code has problems due to infinite compile-time recursion. Clang 3.6.0 gives an error about recursive template instantiation depth, and doesn't terminate; while GCC 4.9.2 remains silent, and also doesn't terminate.

This is a simpler example than I was originally faced with, and certainly the second overload of `bar` could be given `int` as a return type; in this case, the first overload is chosen for the call to `bar` in `main`; as I'd originally hoped. Why does the application of `decltype` not resolve to the first overload, which is specialised for `Foo`?

The second (default) template parameter of `Foo` seems to hide more verbose messages regarding the recursion issue here. This would have been useful in the original context.

```
template <typename T, typename A = T>
struct Foo {};

template <typename T, typename A>
int bar(const Foo<T,A> &x) { return 0; }

template <typename T>
auto bar(const T &x)
 -> decltype(bar(Foo<T>{})){    
    return   bar(Foo<T>{});    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Foo<char> f;    
  bar(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because the `decltype` expression needs to work out the return type of `bar` for those arguments, so it needs to instantiate all the `bar` templates, which involves looking at that `decltype` expression which needs to work out the return type of `bar` for those arguments, so it needs to instantiate all the `bar` templates... I'm sure you can imagine how that eventually leads to the compiler falling over.

In C++14 we can just omit the trailing return type to avoid all this work. In C++11 we can disable that overload for when `T` is a `Foo`:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    struct is_foo : std::false_type{};
    template <typename T, typename A>
    struct is_foo<Foo<T,A>> : std::true_type{};
}
template <typename T>
using is_foo = detail::is_foo<typename std::decay<T>::type>;

template <typename T, typename A>
int bar(const Foo<T,A> &x) { return 0; }

template <typename T, 
   typename = typename std::enable_if<!is_foo<T>::value>::type>
auto bar(const T &x)
 -> decltype(bar(Foo<T>{})){    
    Foo<T> b{};
    return bar(b);    
}
```